# how to do controller specs in rspec 1.3.2

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-2, rspec1

I've got an old rails app, which is in rails 2.3, that I want to upgrade to rails 3. However before I do this I want to add some rspec tests. Due to it being rails 2.3, I believe I've got to use rspec 1.3, which is where I get the trouble.

I've got a simple controller:

```
class MySimpleController < ApplicationController
   def index
      ...
   end
end
```

And I'm trying to write a success spec under spec/controllers/my_simple_controller_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe MySimpleController do
   controller_name 'my_simple' #do i need this?
    it "should get index" do
       get "index"
       response.should be_sucess
    end
end
```

I get the error

```
ActionController::RoutingError in 'MySimpleController should get index'
Need controller and action!
```

I thought the fact that I'm doing describe the same class name would work.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this,

```
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :index
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
```

Also there is no need to write controller name and action.